# How to display the most recent file when the user is asked to input three filenames in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to develop a shell script which asks the user to enter three filenames and then the script will output the most recent file that was created. However, every time I run my code, it automatically goes to the elseif section and displays "No filename found ....EXITING"

What mistake am I doing in my code?

```
read -p "Enter three filenames : $1 $2 $3 "
if [ -f "$1" ] && [ -f "$2" ] && [ -f "$3" ]
then 
ls -t $read | head n1
else
echo "No filename found .......EXITING"
fi
```

Comment: run your code thru https://shellcheck.net. Be sure to include `#!/bin/bash` as the first line (or specify the shell you are using, if not `bash`). Good luck.

Comment: `$1` to `$3` refer to positional parameters, not  what is read through `read`. Check `read --help` : you're supposed to pass variables names to `read` which it will populate with the data being read.

Comment: Am I missing something, why not just:    `$ ls -1c File1 File2 File3  | head -1`   The issue also is the `-t` flag.  `-t` is last modified.  The original question was "most recent file *created*`   Which means using `-c` for `ctime`.   `$ man ls`

Answer (score 3):

To read into multiple variables, you have to specify the variable names:

```
read -rp "Enter three filenames: " f1 f2 f3
```

`-r` makes sure backslashes aren't interpreted in the input.

Now, instead of `$1` etc., you use `f1` and friends:

```
if [[ -f $f1 ]] && [[ -f $f2 ]] && [[ -f $f3 ]]; then
```

I've used the Bash-specific `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]` here as it is more forgiving regarding quoting (and does it for us).

And finally, parsing `ls` is an [antipattern](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). You could compare the files directly instead:

```
newest=$f1
[[ $f2 -nt $newest ]] && newest=$f2
[[ $f3 -nt $newest ]] && newest=$f3
printf '%s\n' "$newest"
```

All together:

```
read -rp "Enter three filenames: " f1 f2 f3
if [[ -f $f1 ]] && [[ -f $f2 ]] && [[ -f $f3 ]]; then
    newest=$f1
    [[ $f2 -nt $newest ]] && newest=$f2
    [[ $f3 -nt $newest ]] && newest=$f3
    printf '%s\n' "$newest"
else
    echo "No filename found" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```